# \s doesn't work in matchstr

Tags: regular-expression

I have this in my `init.vim`:

```
autocmd TextChangedI <buffer> echom matchstr(getline(line('.')), "^\s*y")
```

I was expecting to get the first part of the line if I enter something like that:

```
        y
 y
```

but it only prints `y` if I enter this:

```
y
```

according to the docs, `\s` represents the space and tab character:

```
|/\s|   \s  \s  whitespace character: <Space> and <Tab>
```

Now if I use this instead:

```
autocmd TextChangedI <buffer> echom matchstr(getline(line('.')), "^ *y")
```

then it works as expected. Why does the first pattern not work? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `:help expr-"` and write `matchstr(…, '^\s*y')` to avoid the back-slash disappearing.

Comment: Ooooh that makes sense! Thank you!